# MSVS2015 Linux Debug starting gdbserver failed

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug a linux c++ application on a remote offsite server and I got this message:

[image: gdbserver error]

Any ideas? I've tried debugging it on an onsite linux machine (through MSVS2015 on windows) and it works fine.

Comment: Do they have gdbserver installed? Which version?

Comment: Yeah it's installed on the remote server and it's v7.11.1. I just checked the onsite linux machine it's the same there.

Comment: @n.m. don't know if i have to tag, but just in case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a snapshot of the server prior to installing gdbserver. It worked after I installed all the components again by doing this:

1. sudo apt-get install openssh-server g++ gdb gdbserver

Don't know what fixed it but this worked...